# Stored procedure to generate a unique id column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Good day

I have a situation where two users are saving data to the same database and there are primary key conflicts.

Is it possible to write a stored procedure or trigger which will generate a unique identity by adding two columns.

For instance: I have `table2` related to `table1` by `Table1ID`. Increment and seed is 1 for both.

If I had to add a row to `table2` I would like the autogenerated ID number to be added to a text column thereby making it unique. So the ID would be something like `JoeSoap5`.

Comment: Show your database schema please.  You don't say what you are using as your primary key here.

Comment: Why not just use `INT IDENTITY` and let SQL Server handle all the other gory details ... that's **by far** the easiest solution - don't try to generate your own unique keys - that's just way too messy and error-prone....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generated something unique you can use the build-in function "[NEWID()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx)". Type and executed the following code:

```
SELECT NEWID()
```

If you need to insert record in second table when record in your first table is inserted, is is possible to implement this using [TRIGGERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx). In your case you can use "AFTER INSERT TRIGGER" or "BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER" - generally this will be a piece of code that will be executed AFTER/BEFORE row in your first table is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify your SQL Server version.

SQL 2012 introduces the concept of a sequence - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx - which would allow you to do just what you want.